# match with language R for getting the position

Tags: r, match

I am using match for getting if an element is in a list. For example my list is:

```
  c("a","b","h","e"...) and so on
```

if I want to see if element h is in the list I am using match in this way:

```
  if ("h" %in% v){do something}
```

How I can get the position of where it finds the element in the list?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to know the position use `which`

```
l <- c("a","b","h","e")
which(l=='h') 
[1] 3   # It'll give you the position, 'h' is the third element of 'l'
```

Note that `l` is a vector, not a list as you mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to know the position, use `match`:

```
l <- c("a","b","h","e")
match("h", l)
```

It won't make any different here, but generally it will be much faster.

Answer (score 3):

The `which` function would tell you where in a vector an item would "match". The `%in%` will return a logical vector of the same length as its first argument, and `if` will only look at the first logical value so will not work well by itself. You could do this:

```
if( any("h" %in& v) ) { do something }
```

The `any` function allows you to "collapse" the result of `%in%`